# SQL left Join Error on multiple JOIN

Tags: mysql

```
Here is my query 

SELECT item.item, item.id as itemID,item.item_sku,O.serial_no,transaction.id, transaction.t_price, transaction.t_unit, transaction.total_amount, transaction.transaction_type, transaction.comment, transaction.created from transaction

LEFT JOIN item ON transaction.item_id = item.id
LEFT JOIN order O  ON transaction.order_no=o.order_no
WHERE transaction_type='buy' ORDER BY transaction.created DESC
```

But its showing this error .. why ??

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order  o ON transaction.order_no=o.order_no WHERE transaction_type='buy' ORDER ' at line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html), so you need to escape it. Check this [Stackoverflow answer](https://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows/254077#254077) on how to use back-tick to escape the reserved words in your queries.

Please check this one:

```
SELECT item.item, item.id as itemID,item.item_sku,O.serial_no,transaction.id, transaction.t_price, transaction.t_unit, transaction.total_amount, transaction.transaction_type, transaction.comment, transaction.created 
FROM transaction

LEFT JOIN item ON transaction.item_id = item.id
LEFT JOIN `order` O  ON transaction.order_no = o.order_no
WHERE transaction_type='buy' 
ORDER BY transaction.created DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

And you can write a shorter form when you use ALIAS.

```
SELECT
    i.item
    , i.id as itemID
    , i.item_sku
    , o.serial_no
    , t.id
    , t.t_price
    , t.t_unit
    , t.total_amount
    , t.transaction_type
    , t.comment
    , t.created
FROM transaction
LEFT JOIN item i ON t.item_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN `order` o ON t.order_no=o.order_no
WHERE transaction_type='buy'
ORDER BY t.created DESC;
```